# Count output in C

Tags: c, count, character

My program input is 6 and output is `6! = 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 720`. So i want to count all characters in output including 'x' and space characters. And after that i want to print * as output character number above the output. This is code i used for factorial but i couldn't find how to count characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fact_calc ( int n );

int main (void)
{
    int number;

    scanf ("%d", &number);
    printf ("%d! = %d x", number, number);
    fact_calc ( number );
}

void fact_calc ( int n )
{
    static long long int total = 1;

    if ( n != 2 && n >= 2 )
    {
        printf (" %d x", n - 1);
        total *= n;
        fact_calc ( n - 1 );
    }
    else
    {
        total *= 2;
        printf (" %d = %lld", n - 1, total);
    }
}
```

Comment: regarding: `printf ("%d! = %d x", number, number);`  if (for instance) the user entered `10` then this will output:  `10! = 10 x`  Is that what you actually want to output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf` returns the number of character it printed. So you could sum all the return values of `printf` calls to get the total.

Here's your code modified:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fact_calc ( int n, int *count );

int main (void)
{
    int number;
    int count = 0;

    scanf ("%d", &number);
    int t = printf ("%d! = %d x", number, number);
    if (t > 0) count += t;
    fact_calc ( number, &count );
    printf("\nTotal chars printed: %d\n", count);
}

void fact_calc ( int n, int *count )
{
    static long long int total = 1;

    if ( n != 2 && n >= 2 )
    {
        int t = printf (" %d x", n - 1);
        if (t > 0) *count += t;
        total *= n;
        fact_calc ( n - 1, count );
    }
    else
    {
        total *= 2;
        int t = printf (" %d = %lld", n - 1, total);
        if (t > 0) *count += t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to dont print printf in this code  `int t = printf ("%d! = %d x", number, number)`  i just want to count characters

Comment: @semicolon Do you mean you don't want to print anything at all and just count?

Comment: My purpose is print asterisks as number of output character before the printf. So i have count output first , print asterisks and  then print factorial

Comment: You can use `snprintf` to print into a buffer (use snprintf's return value to count the chars in the same way). Then print asterisks and then print the buffer at last. E.g. `char buf[25]; int count = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%d\n", 5); /* print 'count' asterisks here */; printf("%s", buf);`.

Comment: the posted code will fail when the value entered by the user is greater than (about) 14.  and even if it did not overflow, the recursion will cause the stack to (soon) overflow and result in a crash.

Comment: If the user enters 0, or a value < 0 the output will be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an int count that you increase with every character you add to your output, or you can output it to a file, and count that file size using `getline()`.

Answer (score 0):

the function: `printf()` returns the number of characters displayed, so you could simply keep track of the sum of those returned values